# How to Get Div Height Equal to Percentage of Window Width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My plan is to have the background of my website be, basically, a grid of squares. The problem is I need the squares to be, well, squares, meaning the width and height need to be the same. They also, however, need to fill the entire page with no cut-off squares on one side, and they need to re-size (essentially, they need to be percentages.) Let me know if this isn't clear - as I'm sure you all will.

I've considered a couple (well, two) different approaches to this, the first one being simple CSS. I know there's VH for vertical height, which detects the height of the screen and turns it into a measurement. Perhaps there's an equivalent for width? If so, I could just set it to 1 W x 1 W, for example. But I haven't been able to find one.

If that's not possible, I'm pretty sure the only other option would be jQuery. I'd have to have a function that got the width of the screen in pixels, and have a variable (X) equal to the width divided by 100. I could then set the height to 10X and the width to 10%. The problem with this is the function would have to be run on every screen re-size, and considering the number of squares I have that might get a little laggy on slower internet connections.

Maybe I'm over-complicating this. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but you could do `$(window).width();` then set the divs height with it.

Comment: oooh, I just realized you meant to have the same aspect ratio for the divs relative to the window width and height. Then you should just get the width and height of the window, then `height / width * div width = new div height` I hope thats what you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `vw` unit (which works based on the viewport/window width).
`1vw` means 1/100 th of the window width.

Comment: This actually has way higher support than I thought. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

padding is calculated based on width, so you can set your elements to have a 0 height, and just set the padding.

**html:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="tenth">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        6
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        7
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        8
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        9
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        10
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        11
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        12
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        13
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        14
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        15
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        16
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        17
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        18
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        19
    </div>
    <div class="tenth">
        20
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#wrapper{
    font-size:0;
}
.tenth {
    font-size:1rem;
    height: 0;
    width: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0;
}
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/xc7Lgzr9/

Comment: I know that you already accepted an answer, however hopefully this answer simplifies things for you drastically.  Also, please note that `font-size:0;` on the wrapper keeps spaces from appearing between your divs, but you could use floating divs instead. `box-sizing:border-box;` keeps everything but the margin of the box within it's width and height, so there are not funky calculation errors and extra wrapping.